# While loop to output a list from SQL on a per users group permission basis returns duplicate results

Tags: php, mysql

**DISCLAIMER:** Before I continue I would like to state that I am not a PHP pro or anything like that, I haven't even touched PHP for 3-4 years (where then I knew way more) which makes it even harder for me to understand the issue, I've been looking online but didn't get far sadly so I decided to post a question here

P.S: About my code, I know that better SQL methods can be used but as it stands for now I just want to figure out what is wrong with my code and then I can take care of "improving" it

I know that I am probably approaching this in the wrong way (at first I thought its only my sql query)

Code:

```php
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost');
header('Content-type: application/json');
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "local_database", "example_db");
// Pull Member data
function getMember($data) {
    try {
        $select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM store_members WHERE name = '{$data}'");
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);
        mysqli_free_result($select);
    } catch (RuntimeException $e) {
        $result["error"] = "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
    
    return $result;
}
// Function that takes 2 strings and tries to find a match against a list, if a match is found it will be returned.
// Example Usage: (1) echo InGroupID(1, "2, 8", "10, 3, 8"); (2) echo InGroupID(10, "2, 8", "10, 3, 6"); (3) echo InGroupID(10, "2, 8", "10, 3, 8"); || (1) Result: 8, (2) Result: 10 (3) Result: 10
function InGroupID($maingroup, $secondary_groups = FALSE, $customgrouplist = FALSE) {
    $member->split_sgroups = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $secondary_groups);
    $groups->permitted = array(4, 2, 6); // 4 = Admins, 2 = Moderators, 6 = Private Users (default list if none provided)
    if($customgrouplist !== FALSE)
        $customgrouplist = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $customgrouplist);
    else
        $customgrouplist = $groups->permitted;
    
    $sgroup_match = array_intersect($member->split_sgroups, $customgrouplist);
    $key = array_search($maingroup, $customgrouplist);
    if($key !== false)
        return $customgrouplist[$key];
    elseif(($secondary_groups !== FALSE) && ($sgroup_match !== FALSE)) {
        sort($sgroup_match);
        return $sgroup_match["0"];
    }
    else
        return false;
    
    return false;
}
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `store_products`");
$res = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >= 1) {
    $mmbr = getMember("Admin");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { // duplicates results for me, if I disable the first while it will display products based only on permissions from 1 row and not accordingly to each product
        $getGroup = InGroupID($mmbr["main_group_id"], $mmbr["secondary_group_ids"], $row["product_permissions"]); // tries to find a match for members permissions in store products, if found, the match will be returned so we can use it to filter products in the next while.
        $cQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `product_name`,`price`,`quantity`,`product_permissions` FROM `store_products` WHERE CONCAT(',', product_permissions, ',') like '%{$getGroup}%'"); // product_permissions example "5, 9, 10"
        // SELECT `product_name`,`price`,`quantity` FROM `store_products` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('{$getGroup}',product_permissions) -> this won't work for values after the first comma because it is seperated by comma and space and not just comma
        if(!empty($getGroup)) { 
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cQuery)) { // if 1st while is off it will display rows based on matching permissions from first row only and not each accordingly
                $row2["price"] = intval($row2["price"]);
                $row2["quantity"] = intval($row2["quantity"]);
                // Debug, can be ignored.
                $row2["main_group_id"] = $mmbr["main_group_id"];
                $row2["secondary_group_ids"] = $mmbr["secondary_group_ids"]; 
                $row2["($)getGroup"] = $getGroup;
                $res[] = $row2;
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($res);
}
else {
    $res[0] = array(
        "product_name" => "no_products_available_foruser",
        "price" => 0,
        "quantity" => 0
    );
    echo json_encode($res);
}
```

**SQL Tables Used:**

TABLE `store_members`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                          store_members                          |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------------+
| id | name      | password | main_group_id | secondary_group_ids |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Admin     |    ---   | 4             | 8                   |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------------+
|  2 | Moderator |    ---   | 2             | 8, 3                |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------------+
|  3 | VIP_User  |    ---   | 8             | 3                   |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------------+
|  4 | Shopper12 |    ---   | 3             | NULL                |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------------+
```

TABLE `store_products`:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              store_products                              |
+----+----------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------+
| id | product_name               | price | quantity | product_permissions |
+----+----------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | iPhone X - VIP Edition     |   30  | 5        | 4, 2, 8             | 
+----+----------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------+
|  2 | iPhone X - Public          |   45  | 200      | 2, 8, 3             | 
+----+----------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------+
|  3 | iPhone X - Private Edition |   15  | 3        | 4, 2                | 
+----+----------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------+
|  4 | Pixel 4 - VIP Edition      |   28  | 10       | 4, 2, 8             | 
+----+----------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------+
|  5 | Pixel 4 - Private Edition  |   12  | 8        | 4, 2                | 
+----+----------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------+
|  6 | Pixel 4 - Public           |   42  | 164      | 2, 8, 3             | 
+----+----------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------+
|  7 | Pixel 4 - Subscribers      |   40  | 100      | 6                   | 
+----+----------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------+
```

Here's what the code should do basically,

**Short Version:**

Pulls product list from an sql table `store_products` by a users group id/sub group ids from `store_members` table and displays the list in json.

**Long Version:**

PHP Script to get `main_group_id`, `secondary_group_ids` values **from** `store_members` table by a given members `name` **and** then takes `main_group_id`, `secondary_group_ids` and searches for any match at another table (`store_products`) at column `product_permissions` **finally**, if there's a match the certain product will be displayed, it should search for a match for every product separately from `store_products` and then display it in json.

**The Problem:** Duplicated results, here's how it happens to me -

Let's get the product list for user "Admin" in a json file,
Member Properties - **Name: Admin** , **Main Group ID: 4** (Admins) , **Secondary Group IDS: 8** (VIP)

A while loop should calculate how many rows to display based on permission match for each row individually, For example **My Main Group ID** & **Secondary Group IDS** are **4** and **8** which means I have permissions to view products list for groups **4** and **8**, I should get **6 results** then because **4** and **8** exist in these rows `product_permissions`, Instead I get duplicate results and I sometimes don't get products that match permission for my subgroup, especially for products that have two of my groups in their `product_permissions`

**It's all calculated like that:**

```
InGroupID(4, 8, "4, 2, 8"); // 4 (my main group), 8 (secondary), iPhone X - VIP Edition's `product_permissions` || returns 4 because there is a match for 4 in 4,2,8 (first match gets returned first)

InGroupID(4, 8, "2, 8, 3"); // 4 (my main group), 8 (secondary), iPhone X - Public's `product_permissions` || returns 8 because there is a match for 8 in 2,8,3 (first match gets returned first)
```

The match from `InGroupID` will be passed to `$getGroup` through an SQL query (`` SELECT `product_name`,`price`,`quantity`,`product_permissions` FROM `store_products` WHERE CONCAT(',', product_permissions, ',') like '%{$getGroup}%' ``) and will loop with `while` for each product in the list to display accordingly

**Notice:** The Enteries below appear at the json file and are just for "debugging" purposes to better understand the problem, ignore them if you'd like as they are not a part of the actual code.

```
"product_permissions": "X, X, X",
"main_group_id": "X",
"secondary_group_ids": "X, X",
"($)getGroup": "X"
```

**Default Output** (original code): https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb675fd3 - shows all results but has too many duplicates

**Without the 1st while-loop** (`// while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {`): https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbebc3eb

**Expected Output** (what I wanted): https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb656906

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You make a select and receive data, that we don't know and then you make some thing in php and have an result that we also don't know how it looks like. You see the pattern. So post your sanitized data show the result of your proceedings and then finally show a desired result.

Comment: Analyze the content of your variables (`var_dump()` or use a debugger). Find the first occurance where a variable doesn't contain what it should contain. Only post the code, that generates that (invalid) content. Hardcode any input for that code. Then post, what the content should be.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Can't make heads or tails of what is supposed to be going on here, let alone what might be wrong. The first two lines of your InGroupID function are referencing undefined variables. I'm sure if you turn on proper error logging you'll find a lot of problems to fix.

Comment: @miken32 even with everything that was provided it is still hard to understand what's going on?  well I really am a failure then.. I spent some time editing this and trying to make this easier for everyone.. this should of been a simple script to pull product list from an sql table by a users group id/sub group ids from store members table, that's it.. idk how I made it that hard to understand. Also, about the `InGroupID` function - It outputs two warnings which are the same "Creating default object from empty value" I believe this isn't a problem and you say it might be a problem?

Comment: I think you are over-complicating it. I there a reason to query separately?

Comment: Your design is really bad, i looked at your data, but without major further complications i can' see a good solution to your problem. My thougts on your problem you can sse here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c77bb4aa3d0e58fa7a1d4fcf3ea44544  it doesn't work as i thought because there is no mathem,atocval solution to your problem, if the group rights where ascending  or descending you only need to check the "lowest" usergroup to check  against main_group_id of the user and you had all 
p

Comment: My paragraph is a little bit too long for the comment so I posted it at another website, please have a look
@Ghostff https://justpaste.it/2rk5y
and nbk - https://justpaste.it/1ovmi

Comment: Yes, use ` SELECT DISTINCT` and join them with `WHERE OR`.

Comment: @Ghostff is that on the first query or the second? because I did try ``SELECT DISTINCT`` on the second and it didn't work. can you share an example to a query?

Comment: on the second, and yes it wont work because you are doing it inside a loop. i will make a gist or something for you when i have time.

Comment: @Ghostff Hey, I have found a solution to my problem. I came to a conclusion that I needed something like `array_unique` but with a key input to filter out duplicates by `product_name` (key in returned array from sql) so I looked over google and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596110/remove-duplicates-based-on-a-specific-key , tried to use this solution and I got it working perfectly! Tell me if you had an other solution in mind or a better code/method for this so I would know if to post an answer to my own question or not. regardless, Thank You for your time!!!

Comment: @OverSpan that is fine, But you are Bruteforceing. So if you dont care about perf, you are fine.

Comment: @Ghostff I do care, but nothing else has came into my mind but this, so as I said.. if you have any other approaches/methods for this I'd be happy if you share them

Comment: take a look at https://3v4l.org/pM4We

Comment: @Ghostff wow, your approach works. And so much better and effective, I don't know how I didn't think of that. Kudos to you sir, I just had to add another while because ``mysqli_fetch_assoc`` outputs 1 row only. here's the working code:https://3v4l.org/e1tWv , Make an answer so I can choose it and mark this as solved, Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [PDO][1]

```php
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `store_products`");
$res = [];

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >= 1) {
    $mmbr = getMember("Admin");
    $sql  = 'SELECT `product_name`,`price`,`quantity`,`product_permissions` FROM `store_products` WHERE';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        // bool / int
        $getGroup = InGroupID($mmbr["main_group_id"], $mmbr["secondary_group_ids"], $row["product_permissions"]);

        // Concat all the existing group into a query string.
        if($getGroup) { 
            $sql .=  " CONCAT(',', product_permissions, ',') like '%{$getGroup}%' OR";
        }
    }

    // Remove last OR
    $sql       = rtrim($sql, 'OR');

    $prepare   = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    // If finally using PDO, you can do this instead
    // $res = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Saves you from another loop.
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prepare)) {
        $res[] = $row;
    }

    // Tested and Working, Thanks!!
    echo json_encode($res);
}
else {
    $res = [
        "product_name" => "no_products_available_foruser",
        "price"        => 0,
        "quantity"     => 0    
    ];

    echo json_encode($res);
}


  [1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
```